# Is there any problem if I booked Multi Destinations ticket?

Tags: visas, air-travel, airports, airlines

I'm from Tunisia and I got a Schengen visa from the Austrian Embassy for 28 days, the “duration of stay”, and the number of entries is 1 and the validity of the visa is from 02/08/2015 to 13/09/2015.

I'm going to book a ticket (Tunisair) from Tunis to Vienna one way  , and I'll go back to Tunisia from Paris on Air France.

Is there any problem if I booked Multi Destinations ticket (be the way the Airlines are not the same one)?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem you can have if you will stay more than 28 days inside the Schengen Area.

You can back to Tunisia from France or another Schengen country with the same or a different airline, but because your visa was issued by Austria, it's better that Austria is part of your trip.

In addition take with you a printed copy of your return ticket details and hotel reservations.

Have a nice stay in Europe!

Comment: His visa has a "number of entries of one" so he should make sure he's not leaving the schengen zone. That is, do not go from Austria to France via a country that's not in the Schengen zone I suppose

Comment: Thank you very much.
And I'm going to visite France after finishing my Sommer course in Austria and I'm not going to leave the Schengen area, because I'm going to take a flight from Austria, Vienna to France, Paris.